# Interchanging finite sum(over prime numbers) and integration

Tags: integration, summation

Here is an expression I am trying to prove:
$$ \sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\ln(p)}{p}\int_{p}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2} = \int_{2}^{x} \sum_{p\leq u } \frac{\ln(p)}{p} \frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2} + \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\ln(p)}{p}$$
where summation is over p  (prime number) $\leq x$.

I tried to solve this in this way.

$$ \sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\ln(p)}{p}\int_{p}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2} =\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{\ln(p)}{p} \int_{p}^{x}  \frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2} + 
\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{\ln(p)}{p} \int_{x}^{\infty}  \frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2} $$
$$\hspace{3cm}= \sum_{p\leq x} \frac{\ln(p)}{p} \int_{p}^{x}  \frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2} + 
\frac{1}{\ln(x)} \sum_{p\leq x} \frac{\ln(p)}{p}$$

But I am not able to prove
$$ \sum_{p\leq x} \frac{\ln(p)}{p} \int_{p}^{x}  \frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2}=  \int_{2}^{x} \sum_{p\leq u } \frac{\ln(p)}{p} \frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2} $$

I would like to know the solution for this or some hint. Or is my approach not correct?

Comment: Hint: [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula)

Comment: Yeah got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{\ln n}{n}~~&\text{if $n$ is prime}\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}\end{align}
and $$\phi(y)=\int_y^x\frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2}$$
Then we have $\phi(x)=0$ and $\phi'(y)=-\frac{1}{y(\ln(y))^2}$. Hence [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) gives us:\begin{align*}
\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\ln(p)}{p}\int_p^x\frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2}=\sum_{1.5<n\leq x} a_n\phi(n)&=A(x)\phi(x)-A(1.5)\phi(1.5)-\int_{1.5}^xA(u)\phi'(u)du\\
&=\int_2^x\sum_{p\leq u}\frac{\ln(p)}{p}\frac{du}{u(\ln(u))^2}
\end{align*}
where $A(u)=\sum_{0\leq n\leq u}a_n$. (The '$1.5$' was only necessary here so that the conditions in the link are satisfied, note that $A(u)=0$ for $u<2$)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it from the hint.